# What's the difference between input and :input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

I've seen two ways of select `input`:

```
$("input")
```

and

```
$(":input")
```

Is there any difference between them?

Comment: $('input') = with only the element name, selects only HTML <input> elements.

$(':input') = with the colon, selects all form input type elements, including <input>, <select>, <textarea>, and <button> elements.

Comment: What prevented you from reading the documentation, @Luminous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("input")` only select the `<input>` element.

`$(":input")` is a [jQuery extension](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) wich will select these elements: `<input>`, `<select>`,`<textarea>` and `<button>`

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/q3Hcc/)**

Comment: What do you mean by jQuery extension? it's a part of base jQuery.

Comment: @ColinDeClue `Because :input is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification` I just take the statement from the docs itself.

Comment: Ah, the `:input` *selector* is a jQuery extension. (so you wouldn't be  able to use it in CSS)

Answer (score 2):

Just read the docs. The [`:input` selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/):

> Selects all `input`, `textarea`, `select` and `button` elements.

Whereas `input` is a simple type selector and will only match `input` elements.

Answer (score 0):

The first `$('input')` selects all `input` elements, and is able to be passed to `document.querySelectorAll()` (if implemented in the host browser), which makes the selection a little faster.

The latter, `$(':input')`, however, is a jQuery-specific selector (and which therefore *cannot* be passed to `document.querySelectorAll()` in order to increase selection speed), which selects all `input`-similar tags (for want of a better phrase), including `input`, `textarea` and `select`.

References:

- [`:input` selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

`$("input")` will match only `<input>` elements.

`$(":input")` on the other hand will match all `<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>` and `<button>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

[As docs says](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)

> The :input selector basically selects all form controls.

where as

`$("input")` only selects  elements.

Answer (score 0):

The `:input` is  selector:

Selects all input, textarea, select and button elements.

input is a simple element selector and will only match input elements.

Answer (score 0):

`$("input")` is a specific case of [a very general syntax](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/). That is, in general, `$("x")` selects all `x` nodes (`<x></x>` nodes). So, here, it gives you all `<input>` nodes.

`$(':input')` is [a very specific *special* selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/), which is designed to select `<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>` and `<button>` nodes. You cannot replace the text after the `:` with just anything, though there are [other such special selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).